# Get all linear congruences of $3x\equiv 6(mod9)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So to solve this I'm told that you find the gcd of 3 and 9, which is (3,9)=3 and since 3|6, there are 3 classes of solutions which can be found using the diophantine equation $3x+9y=6$. I was only able to fine one solution which is $3(-1)+9(1)=6$ so $x=-1+9n\equiv 8  \pmod 9$. Is there a way to find the other 2 solutions? Or do I have to just keep trying values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

$$3x\equiv 6\pmod 9 \iff3x-6=9k \iff x-2=3k \iff x\equiv 2\pmod 3$$

then as the least residue system modulo $9$ is

$$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$$

we see that $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$ when $x=2,5,8$. Therefore, the solutions are $x\equiv 2,5,8\pmod 9$

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you divide the modulus by 3 as well, so you get $x\equiv2\pmod 3$, which leads to the solutions $x\equiv2,5,8\pmod 9$.

Comment: Sorry seems to be a bit of a gap there for me. How did you get $x\equiv 2(mod3)$ and how did that lead to the other solutions?

Comment: @DylanY You're dividing both sides of the original equation by 3, but since 3 is a factor of the modulus you have to divide the modulus by 3.  Once you have that, the numbers mod 9 that are equivalent to 2 mod 3 are 2, 2+3, and 2+6.